# What is the use of `HTTP End Point` in Jitterbit?

Tags: jitterbit

We have started using `Jitterbit`. Thanks for the pretty good product.

Can anyone tell me what is the use of `HTTP End Point` ?

It is used for request or response ?

I believe it is used for only response. When external system send Response to us calling our HTTP end point, we will use the response data and process the operation.

Or else external server will request calling our HTTP End point, we will process the request using many operation .

Comment: Did you figure anything out on this? I have the same question that you do.

Comment: Yaah, I do. I will answer it.

Comment: Check the answer. You are working on Jitterbit ? Let us have a group for it..

Answer (score 2):

HTTP endpoint is used to call the `Jitterbit Server Endpoint`

Let me explain...

Using Jitterbit you have called a webservice (External Source). You got the response same time. Here request and response used same http session.

You are expecting some response from external source after 2 days. You must have some `listener`in the Jitterbit server. That listener will kick-in you jitterbit operations.

Ex:- External source will call below URL.

http://www.yourjitterbitsername:46908/endpoint

```
www.yourjitterbitsername :- Your jitterbit server
46908 : port number
endpoint :- Jitterbit Endpoint.
```

When external source hit the URL, it executes the corresponding `Jitterbit Operation` that you have mesnioned in the `Http Endpoint` synchronously or asynchronously. (You can do in settings)

You can store the request variable in to the jitterbit global variable. Request variable means, the request external source is requesting to the jitterbit server.